# Numpy append multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, append

In R it is very easy to combine multiple vectors, for instance:

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
b<-c(4,5,6,7)
c<-c(8,9,10)
#combine to
d<-c(a,b,c)
```

This is what I want to recreate by using NumPy.

I tried to achieve this using np.append, and it works fine as long as all arrays have the same length, for instance:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.array([7,8,9])
d = np.append(a,(b,c)) #works fine
```

However

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6,7])
c = np.array([8,9,10])
d = np.append(a,(b,c)) #does not work fine
```

The result is: `[1,2 3 array([4,5,6,7]) array([8,9,10])]`. How do I turn this into a classic NumPy array `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`?

Comment: use [np.hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this function:

```
np.concatenate([a,b,c])
```

am I right?

`np.concatenate` is used to concatenate arrays with same number of dimension, but different size, along one specific axis (`0` axis by default). In your case, since you have just one dimension and you want to concatenate on the unique dimension you have, you can also use `np.hstack([a,b,c])`, as mentioned by @Sembei Norimaki in the comments.

EDIT to answer you question in the comments:

in the source code of numpy:

```
if axis is None:
    if arr.ndim != 1:
        arr = arr.ravel()
    values = ravel(values)
    axis = arr.ndim-1
return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

as you can see, the `values` to append are forced to be a numpy array before appending them (this happens in the `ravel` function). Since your arrays have different shape, it is not possible to cast them in an integers numpy array and so a numpy array of numpy arrays is created (try `np.array((b,c))` and see what happens). For this reason your are appending a numpy array of numpy arrays to an integer numpy array and this causes the problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Do you have an explanation though why `np.append` works when the length is the same and otherwise fails?

Comment: @Lars I resumed the problem in the EDIT

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named cover for `concatenate`.  It's ok for adding one value to a 1d array, for anything else use `concatenate` itself or one of the `stack's`.